# How can we change URL from which webpacker packs are served in Rails 5.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, webpacker

I've currently got my webpacker settings to default. My URL for the app would be
`http://myapps.net`
Assets would be served from the `public/packs` directory, after compilation, and the URL while serving those are `http://myapps.net/packs/application-SHA.js` for e.g.

How do I keep serving the assets from `public/packs` but the URL from which the application server serves these assets now is `http://myapps.net/myapp1/packs/application-SHA.js` ?

The intent being I can then use one top level domain, and namespace each individual Rails app, with a path like `myapp1`, `myapp2` etc. and whichever load balancer I use can resolve the packs to the right app instead of going to the top-level domain and failing to find the asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the default `public_output_path` in your `config/webpacker.yml` file to whatever directory you want:

```
production:
  public_output_path: myapp1/packs
```

The default is just `packs`.